# Rollback a SQS message

Tags: python, amazon-sqs, aws-sqs-fifo

I would like to know if one can remove a message from SQS FIFO queue only with the response of `sqs_client.send_message`. I have tried MessageId from the response, but it's not a valid `ReceiptHandle`.

I want to do this because I need to send several messages (like 10), but if one fails, I want to remove all of the ones that didn't failed to be sent.

Comment: No, that is not possible and cannot work because before you could even try to delete the message a consumer could already have picked it up. Do the messages have different MessageGroupIds in your case? It is worth noting that unless you are sending weird (e.g. very large message) it is highly unlikely you will ever encounter individual messages failing in SQS. The most likely reason for that would be a problem with SQS itself at which point deleting messages will most likely not work either.

Comment: may you reply as an answer? i'll accept it